How to turn off authorization and authentication in dev environment?
I have configured authorization, authentication using JWT like this:
public static void AddJwtAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
    {
        JWTOptions jwtOption = new JWTOptions();
        configuration.GetSection(nameof(JWTOptions)).Bind(jwtOption);

        x.SaveToken = true;

        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtOption.SecretKey);
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ...
        };
    });

    services.AddAuthorization();
}

I configured it, but in development environment, I do not want to use authorization and authentication, but it still uses:
builder.Services.AddJwtAuthentication(builder.Configuration);

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
}

